# Casting to an actor

Tags: c++, casting, unreal-engine5

Hello everyone and Happy New Year!

I'm stuck  with a problem. I'm making a project game in UE5 and making an ammo box for my tank to get additional ammo. I made a class AmmoBox:
AmmoBox.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Cannon.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "AmmoBox.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TANKOGEDDON_API AAmmoBox : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    AAmmoBox();

protected:
    UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Components")
    UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Ammo")
    TSubclassOf<ACannon> CannonClass;
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Ammo")
    int additionalAmmo = 5;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnMeshOverlapBegin(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor,
UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const
FHitResult& SweepResult);
```

AmmoBox.cpp

```
#include "AmmoBox.h"
#include "TankPawn.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "Engine/World.h"
#include "GameFramework/PlayerController.h"


// Sets default values
AAmmoBox::AAmmoBox()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = false;

    USceneComponent * sceneCpm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
    RootComponent = sceneCpm;
    Mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
    Mesh->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
    Mesh->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAmmoBox::OnMeshOverlapBegin);
    Mesh->SetCollisionProfileName(FName("OverlapAll"));
    Mesh->SetCollisionEnabled(ECollisionEnabled::QueryAndPhysics);
    Mesh->SetGenerateOverlapEvents(true);


}

void AAmmoBox::OnMeshOverlapBegin(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor,
    UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    ATankPawn * TankPawn = Cast<ATankPawn>(OtherActor);
    TSubclassOf<ACannon> testActor;
    ACannon* Cannon = Cast<ACannon>(testActor);
    if(TankPawn)
    {
        Cannon->AddAmmo(additionalAmmo);
        TankPawn->SetFirstCannon(CannonClass);
        TankPawn->SetupCannon(CannonClass);
        Destroy();
    }
}
```

And have another class Cannon that has an int variable EquippedAmmo and a method AddAmmo():

```
void ACannon::AddAmmo(int addedAmmo)
{
    Ammo+=addedAmmo;
}
```

And I still don't understand casting to quite well. I'm trying to get the AddAmmo method in the AmmoBox.cpp in OnMeshOverlapBegin function to add ammo to my cannon. And Compiler doesn't show any issues. But whenever I overlap an ammobox with my tank the game instantly  crashes. This is what I get:

```
=== Critical error: ===
Error        LogWindows                Fatal error!
Error        LogWindows                Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION writing address 0x0000000000000400
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbb2413250 UnrealEditor-Tankogeddon.dll!ACannon::AddAmmo() [D:\GeekBrains\UE Course\Tankogeddon\Tankogeddon\Source\Tankogeddon\Cannon.cpp:155]
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbb24124f8 UnrealEditor-Tankogeddon.dll!AAmmoBox::OnMeshOverlapBegin() [D:\GeekBrains\UE Course\Tankogeddon\Tankogeddon\Source\Tankogeddon\AmmoBox.cpp:37]
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbb2418e27 UnrealEditor-Tankogeddon.dll!AAmmoBox::execOnMeshOverlapBegin() [D:\GeekBrains\UE Course\Tankogeddon\Tankogeddon\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\Tankogeddon\AmmoBox.gen.cpp:35]
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc21f1bc07 UnrealEditor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc22141837 UnrealEditor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd34e03f4 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd33998fb UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd3a47e9d UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd3a4761d UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd3a94646 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd3a75caa UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd34f08ff UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbb2418504 UnrealEditor-Tankogeddon.dll!ATankPawn::Tick() [D:\GeekBrains\UE Course\Tankogeddon\Tankogeddon\Source\Tankogeddon\TankPawn.cpp:70]
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd34f82b2 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd34bea96 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd4fd5a0f UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd4fdccf8 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc1f783a9d UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc1f783f3e UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc1f78d6af UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd4ff2f0a UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd4ff98b0 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd403f08f UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd40479c0 UnrealEditor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc1d5de5f5 UnrealEditor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc1df6aac6 UnrealEditor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef082f6 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef20d9c UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef20e8a UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef23c4d UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef35564 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ff71ef38736 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc768355a0 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
Error        LogWindows                [Callstack] 0x00007ffc7804485b ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
Log          LogExit                   Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
```

Cannon.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameStructs.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Cannon.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TANKOGEDDON_API ACannon : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public:
    ACannon();

    void Fire();
    void SpecialFire();
    void Reload();
    void ReloadSpecial();
    bool IsReadyToFire();
    bool IsReadyToFireSpecial();

    void AddAmmo(int32 addedAmmo);

    FTimerHandle ReloadTimer;
    FTimerHandle ReloadTimerSpecial;

protected:
    
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Components")
    class UStaticMeshComponent* CannonMesh;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Components")
    class UArrowComponent* ProjectileSpawnPoint;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Components")
    TSubclassOf<class AProjectile> ProjectileClass;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Components")
    ECannonType CannonType = ECannonType::FireProjectile;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    float FireRate = 1.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    float FireRange = 1000.0f;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    float FireDamage = 1.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    int Ammo = 10;
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    int SpecialAmmo = 4;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    float SpecialFireRate = 0.3f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Fire params")
    int SpecialFireProjectilesQty = 4;
    
private:
    bool bReadyToFire = false;
    bool bReadyToFireSpecial = false;

};
```

Cannon.cpp

```
#include "Cannon.h"

#include "Projectile.h"
#include "Components/ArrowComponent.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "TimerManager.h"
#include "Engine/Engine.h"


ACannon::ACannon()
{
    
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = false;

    USceneComponent* sceneComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("SceneRoot"));
    RootComponent = sceneComp;
    
    CannonMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("CannonMesh"));
    CannonMesh->SetupAttachment(sceneComp);

    ProjectileSpawnPoint = CreateDefaultSubobject<UArrowComponent>(TEXT("ProjectileSpawnPoint"));
    ProjectileSpawnPoint->SetupAttachment(CannonMesh);
    
    
}




void ACannon::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    Reload();
    ReloadSpecial();
}



void ACannon::Fire()
{
    if(!IsReadyToFire())
    {
        return;
    } 
    bReadyToFire = false;
    Ammo--;

    if(CannonType == ECannonType::FireProjectile)
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Red, \
            FString::Printf(TEXT("Fire projectile. %d ammo left"), Ammo));
        AProjectile* projectile = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AProjectile>(ProjectileClass, 
            ProjectileSpawnPoint->GetComponentLocation(), ProjectileSpawnPoint->GetComponentRotation());
        if(projectile)
        {
            projectile->Start();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Fire trace")));
        FHitResult hitResult;
        FCollisionQueryParams traceParams = FCollisionQueryParams(FName(TEXT("FireTrace")), true, this);
        traceParams.bTraceComplex = true;
        traceParams.bReturnPhysicalMaterial = false;

        FVector Start = ProjectileSpawnPoint->GetComponentLocation();
        FVector End = Start + ProjectileSpawnPoint->GetForwardVector() * FireRange;

        if(GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(hitResult, Start, End, ECC_Visibility, traceParams))
        {
            DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), Start, hitResult.Location, FColor::Purple, false, \
                1.0f, 0, 5.0f);
            if(hitResult.GetActor())
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp,Warning, TEXT("trace overlap : %s"), *hitResult.GetActor()->GetName());
                hitResult.GetActor()->Destroy();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), Start, End, FColor::Red, false, \
                1.0f, 0, 5.0f);
        }

        
    }

    GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(ReloadTimer, this, &ACannon::Reload, 1/FireRate,  false);
}

void ACannon::SpecialFire()
{
    if(!IsReadyToFireSpecial())
    {
        return;
    }
    bReadyToFireSpecial = false;
    SpecialAmmo --;

    if(CannonType == ECannonType::FireProjectile)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SpecialFireProjectilesQty; i++)
        {
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Blue, \
            FString::Printf(TEXT("Special fire!")));
        }
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Blue, \
            FString::Printf(TEXT(" %d special ammo left"), SpecialAmmo));
    }
    else
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Blue, FString::Printf(TEXT("Fire trace")));
    }

    GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(ReloadTimerSpecial, this, &ACannon::ReloadSpecial, 1/SpecialFireRate,  false);
}



void ACannon::Reload()
{
    bReadyToFire = true;
    if(Ammo <=0)
    {
        bReadyToFire = false;
    }
    
}

void ACannon::ReloadSpecial()
{
    bReadyToFireSpecial = true;
    if(SpecialAmmo <=0)
    {
        bReadyToFireSpecial = false;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.0f, FColor::Blue, FString::Printf(TEXT("No Special Ammo")));
    }
}

bool ACannon::IsReadyToFire()
{
    return bReadyToFire;
}

bool ACannon::IsReadyToFireSpecial()
{
    return bReadyToFireSpecial;
}


void ACannon::AddAmmo(int addedAmmo)
{
    Ammo+=addedAmmo;
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the debugger?

Comment: @n.m. Hello! Just added the debug message in the initial question. If I delete this TSubclassOf<ACannon> testActor;
    ACannon* Cannon = Cast<ACannon>(testActor); 
Cannon->AddAmmo(additionalAmmo);
 Everything will work just fine.

Comment: `TSubclassOf<ACannon> testActor; ACannon* Cannon = Cast<ACannon>(testActor);` does not seem to make much sense – it appears to try to conjure a cannon out of thin air. Shouldn't the cannon be `CannonClass`? (Also, don't forget to check fo the null pointer before dereferencing.)

Comment: So your message tells you that the immediate problem is at line 155 of Cannon.cpp. What does this line do? **Use your debugger** to look at the variables. Notice anything suspicious? What does `this` point at, for example? Perhaps it is a null pointer? Why that might be the case?

Comment: It's really not clear what the relationship between your classes is. Why does the ammo box have a cannon? Why does the ammo box mess with the tank at all? Refilling the ammo sounds like a task for either the tank or its cannon, not the ammo box.

Comment: @n.m. yes It's an AddAmmo method.

Comment: @molbdnilo I've added Cannon .h and .cpp files in the initial post.

Comment: `If I delete this ... Everything will work just fine`. So these lines obviously don't do what you expect them to do. Perhaps your next task is to explain in plain English to your nearest rubber duck what you expect these lines to do, and why. I will help you a bit.  *Cannon should point to this specific cannon (explain which one here) because (explain why here)*.

Comment: @n.m. There's an ammo count in Cannon class. I want the ammo count to increase by the  additionalAmmo amount when my tank overlaps with the ammo box.

Comment: You are not answering any of my questions.

Comment: @n.m. Actually I just solved the issue. As it's a tank overlapping with the ammobox. I made a subclass of the cannon in a TankPawn.h and made a function to trigger AddAmmo function and this solved it. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.